# Does removing white spaces improve website's speed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I have a small doubt. Does removing white space improve website's speed? See, For example, I have the following css -

```
body{
overflow-wrap:break-word;
word-break:break-word;
word-wrap:break-word
}
.hidden{
display:none
}
.invisible{
visibility:hidden
}
```

Does changing the above code to this impact website speed?

```
body{overflow-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-word;word-wrap:break-word}.hidden{display:none}.invisible{visibility:hidden}
```

This is just an example code, There's a lot more in the source code of my site. If yes, Can someone explain how?

Comment: Yes this is called Minification and removing any unused spaces not only makes CSS files smaller but also JS and HTML files as well. More on this here: https://pustelto.com/blog/optimizing-css-for-faster-page-loads/. Without minification is usually "human readable"; we like to read things with spaces and paragraphs for better comprehension, but the browser does not need this.

Comment: All content has to be delivered from the server to the client.  The more content that has to travel over the net from the server to the client, the more time it will take.  Reducing file sizes reduces the total amount of time it takes to fully load a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, removing whitespace on websites does increase speed since it makes the file size smaller, making them load faster (since there are less things that have to be sent). That is also why files like `bootstrap.min.css` are all one line and have short variable names.